# Unreachable Code NOT after return statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a program for a Binary Tree Search and am running into a strange issue. In my class statement I have a section for "in order" which has 2 lines of unreachable code. If I remove the code, the program does not work. But I'm curious as to why it's reading as unreachable? The two lines in question are:

```
            theList.append(bTree.getRootValue())
            self.inOrder(bTree.rightChild,theList)
```

The only return statement I have comes after that definition, so I know it isn't because of a return statement. I've pasted the class build below. The entire program works exactly as it should unless I remove the unreachable code so I feel like that's odd. I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows 11. Thanks!

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.leftChild=None
        self.rightChild=None
        self.key=rootObj

    def insert(self,item):
        if item<self.key:
            if self.leftChild==None:
                self.leftChild=BinarySearchTree(item)
            else:
                self.leftChild.insert(item)
        else:
            if self.rightChild==None:
                self.rightChild=BinarySearchTree(item)
            else:
                self.rightChild.insert(item)
    
    def inOrder(self,bTree,theList):
        if bTree != None:
            self.inOrder(bTree.leftChild,theList)
            theList.append(bTree.getRootValue())
            self.inOrder(bTree.rightChild,theList)
   
    def getRootValue(self):
        return self.key
```

Comment: Why do you think those lines of code are unreachable?  The recursive call on the line before will eventually return, and then those two lines get executed next.

Comment: The code isn't unreachable - whatever linter you are using is wrong. Either use a different linter, or disable your linter for those lines; you could also consider filing a bug report.

Comment: They say they're unreachable in VSC. So that's why I thought that haha

Comment: I also used IDLE and it said the same thing, this is so weird. Thanks!

Comment: I'll absolutely file a bug report - good call Kaya3, I appreciate the insight y'all :)

Comment: Make sure you understand what is emitting the incorrect warning - it is not VS Code or IDLE, so filing a bug report to those projects would not be appropriate. You need to find out which linter VS Code is using.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in my extensions now disabling and enabling them to see which could be causing the issue, once I find it I'll report it

Comment: I might be able to help identify the linter if you edit the question to add the full text of the warning message, possibly a screenshot would help too.

Comment: @kaya3 we already have enough problems with people posting screenshots instead of searchable text, don't encourage it.

Comment: @MarkRansom I said to include the full text **and** possibly a screenshot, not "instead of". I asked for a screenshot because VS Code can show which linter is being used in the status bar, which would not be part of the warning message, and the status bar is not be copy/paste-able text.

Comment: where do you read the report of "unreachable", if in the PROBLEMS tab then the source is mentioned in the error message, if you see it transparent it is PyLance